# Вопрос по созданию бота

Tags: javascript, instagram, бот

Заинтересовалась тема ботов. Можно ли на JS написать например instagram-бота? Функции спама в сообщениях не интересуют. Нужен базовый функционал (возможность выставить лайки к фото). Есть ли какие-то полезные обучающие туториалы\библиотеки по этой теме?(да-да,я знаю, на гитхабе можно стянуть готового инстаграм-бота,написаного на питоне,но я хочу в целях обучения и удовлетворения любопытства написать своего)?

Comment: Можно написать бота на чём угодно, что умеет ходить в интернет, на JS в том числе

Comment: Давайте я вам помогу ;) https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=instagram+bot+js&oq=instagram+bot+js&aqs=chrome..69i57.4230j0j1&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8